# Ruby on Rails: How can I revert a migration with rake db:migrate?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, migration, rake, database-migration

After installing devise MODEL User i got this.

```
class DeviseCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table(:users) do |t|
      t.database_authenticatable :null => false
      t.recoverable
      t.rememberable
      t.trackable

      # t.encryptable
      # t.confirmable
      # t.lockable :lock_strategy => :failed_attempts, :unlock_strategy => :both
      # t.token_authenticatable


      t.timestamps
    end

    add_index :users, :email,                :unique => true
    add_index :users, :reset_password_token, :unique => true
    # add_index :users, :confirmation_token,   :unique => true
    # add_index :users, :unlock_token,         :unique => true
    # add_index :users, :authentication_token, :unique => true
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :users
  end
end
```

Now if i do rake db:migrate the users table will be created.

How can i revert this migration, i.e. how can I delete the users table using rake again ?

Answer (score 157, accepted):

Run the following command

```
rake db:migrate:down VERSION=<version>
```

where `<version>` is the version number of your migration file you want to revert.

eg. if you want to revert a migration with file name 3846656238_create_users.rb

> rake db:migrate:down VERSION=3846656238

Comment: I'm getting an `UnknownMigrationVersionError` but I figured out it's because my migrations are inside `db/migrate/main` , does anybody know a workaround for this to have `db:migrate:down` look inside that specific directory or the migrate subdirectories?

Comment: This is just for rails 3 onwards. My life is in rails 2. So sad

Comment: @morhook This works for rails 3 also.
Check the docs here https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2/migrations.html

Comment: You are right! It works for both rails 2 and rails 3. Thanks @Mahesh for your input!

Answer (score 117):

Just run this command:

```
rake db:rollback
```

Answer (score 68):

I believe there are three options available for reverting migrations (they also overlap):

1. Roll down the *most recent* migration:

   **`rake db:migrate:down`**  # Rails 2 only.
2. Roll down *a number(n) of* recent migrations:

   **`rake db:rollback STEP=n`**
3. Roll down *to* a previous, *specific* version:

   **`$ rake db:migrate:down VERSION=nnn`** # Rails 3 (provide version number also).

Version Number means the SHA(Secure Hash Algorithm) for the commit which is a long hexadecimal number which looks something like 886af3194768917c78e... You can see it by doing `git log`

You can see these commands (and others) with their descriptions by using `rake -T db:` which for rails 3.2 includes:

```
rake db:migrate         # Migrate the database (options: VERSION=x, VERBOSE=false)
rake db:migrate:status  # Display status of migrations
rake db:rollback        # Rolls the schema back to the previous version (specify steps w/ STEP=n)
```

Comment: Roll down _to_ a specific version: `rake db:migrate VERSION=<version number>`

Comment: At least for rails 3.0.20, the first command is wrong. A single `rake db:migrate:down` aborts with the error message "VERSION is required". The [recommended](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#rolling-back) `rake db:rollback` however works.

Comment: As detailed in the answer, Rails 2 ONLY for the first commmand.

Comment: Environment variables are case sensitive so it should be `STEP` and `VERSION`

Comment: To clarify, `$ rake db:migrate:down VERSION=nnn` doesn't roll down _to_ a version, it migrates down _the_ version specified.

Answer (score 16):

You can do rollback and specify how many last migrations will be rollbacked, e.g.

```
rake db:rollback STEP=3
```

for 3 last migrations.

Comment: this is a more quicker and easier way, instead of looking up version numbers if you want to undo the last few migrations

Answer (score 11):

As an new programmer (or to other new programmers)

`rake db:rollback` works about half the time. I start there.

If not, `rake db:migrate:down VERSION=3846656238`

plug in VERSION for the version number of your migration file you want to revert.

Answer (score 10):

```
rake db:migrate:redo
```

It will undo and reapply the last migration.

Answer (score 5):

For rails 5 we can use `rails command instead of rake`

```
rails db:migrate:down VERSION=<version>
```

example

> rails db:migrate:down VERSION=20170330090327

Answer (score 3):

Run this command in your terminal:

```
rake db:migrate:status
```

or

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate:status
```

It shows the status, migration ID's, migration name for all migration we ran previously. select your migration id (i.e your version number) and put that id in the following command after version= ,,, and press enter

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate:down VERSION=
```

Answer (score 1):

## How to Roll back a migration

Another way. I prefer this because you need to be explicit, rather than rolling back - just in case you might make a mistake.

#### (1) First Identify The Migration ID

`rake db:migrate:status`

- Copy the ID number.

[image: Identify the migration to roll back.]

#### (2) Then Roll back the migration

`rake db:migrate:down VERSION=20190802023239`

- Paste the relevant ID number above. Of course, in your case, the migration ID will be different!

.......and now you're off to the races!