# Rails - how to rollback 4th and 5th previous migrations

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have many migrations which are named by time stamp . I just want to know can I roll back 4th and 5th migrations with out using version number ?
i know I can do this way

```
rake db:rollback VERSION=20150612124515
rake db:rollback VERSION=20150612125015
```

but I want some other way. may be not possible, I am just curious.
I know, I can override application.rb to name migrations like the old way. I don't want that too.

This is not a duplicate of [Ruby on Rails: How can I revert a migration with rake db:migrate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7694487/ruby-on-rails-how-can-i-revert-a-migration-with-rake-dbmigrate) because , there he is asking about normal rollback using Version or/and using migrate down method. I know use of this two, I was asking about any other which I mentioned here. Anyway, Thanks Everyone.

Comment: What other way you want?

Comment: anything by which i can easily modify 4th and 5th migrations. something which wont use long version names.

Comment: What's the issue with using the full names? Is not like we don't have filename completion.

Comment: no issue with using full name, I am just curious if There is alternative way.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruby on Rails: How can I revert a migration with rake db:migrate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7694487/ruby-on-rails-how-can-i-revert-a-migration-with-rake-dbmigrate)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there's no other built-in, simple way to roll back a specific migration other than using the `VERSION=...` syntax.